# Interpretation of linear mixed effects model for longitudinal data with lmer

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

Thank you for any help. I am looking at the interaction of time with plasma biomarkers in the brain. Here is the code that I ran:

```
    test = lmer(precuneus.dvr ~ Cage*time + sex*time + race_binary*time + NFLz*time + (1|idno), 
                data = testDFlong30, 
                na.action = na.omit)
```

`precuneus.dvr`: is measured in this unit called DVR,

`race`: 0 = White and 1 = non-White,

`sex`: 0 = Female and 1 = male,

`time`: time between visits for each participant for a brain scan.

My output is here in the image below. How would I interpret the results I see and especially the ones with a time interaction?[image]

Comment: What values can `Cage` and `NFLz` take?

Comment: Please refrain from making substantial edits to a post after it's received an answer, because doing so destroys the work of people who have taken the time to understand & answer your question. If you still have outstanding questions, then you can ask a new Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with `time` and `sex`. Ignoring the other variables for now, your line of best fit is

```
precuneus.dvr = 1.148 + 0.00222 * time + 0.03073 * sex + 0.00417 * time * sex + ...
```

The more time between visits, the higher the predicted value of `precuneus.dvr`, but the line for female participants (`sex = 0`) is

```
1.148 + 0.00222 * time
```

whereas for male participants (`sex = 1`) it is

```
(1.148 + 0.03073) + (0.00222 + 0.00417) * time
```

i.e. the two lines have different intercepts and different slopes. Males start from a higher level and the line is steeper (bigger effect as `time` increases).

You can interpret the interaction of `race_binary` and `time` in a similar way.

The variables `Cage` and `NFLz` are not binary, so we interpret their interaction with `time` a little differently, but the idea is the same. For example, the older the participant, the steeper the slope of `time`.

Centering the variable the way you did (so that `Cage = 0` corresponds to average) is a sensible idea, as we can then interpret the value of `2.224e-02` as the slope of `time` for a participant of average age.